# LESS: Apply a different direction to a Gradient defined in a Mixin

Tags: less, mixins

I have a LESS Mixin defined as follow, to obtain a gradient background

```
.gradient ()
{
  /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(245,246,246,0) 0%, rgba(236,237,239,0) 10%, rgba(219,220,226,0.22) 30%, rgba(184,186,198,0.5) 55%, rgba(221,223,227,0.78) 80%, rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(245,246,246,0)), color-stop(10%,rgba(236,237,239,0)), color-stop(30%,rgba(219,220,226,0.22)), color-stop(55%,rgba(184,186,198,0.5)), color-stop(80%,rgba(221,223,227,0.78)), color-stop(100%,rgba(245,246,246,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(245,246,246,0) 0%,rgba(236,237,239,0) 10%,rgba(219,220,226,0.22) 30%,rgba(184,186,198,0.5) 55%,rgba(221,223,227,0.78) 80%,rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(245,246,246,0) 0%,rgba(236,237,239,0) 10%,rgba(219,220,226,0.22) 30%,rgba(184,186,198,0.5) 55%,rgba(221,223,227,0.78) 80%,rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(245,246,246,0) 0%,rgba(236,237,239,0) 10%,rgba(219,220,226,0.22) 30%,rgba(184,186,198,0.5) 55%,rgba(221,223,227,0.78) 80%,rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(245,246,246,0) 0%,rgba(236,237,239,0) 10%,rgba(219,220,226,0.22) 30%,rgba(184,186,198,0.5) 55%,rgba(221,223,227,0.78) 80%,rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00f5f6f6', endColorstr='#f5f6f6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
```

I need to be able to call this Mixin passing a parameter that can mantain color stops but apply a different direction of gradients, to obtain something like this (in CSS code):

```
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(245,246,246,0), rgba(236,237,239,0) );
```

How to set Mixin in order to reach this result?
Thank you

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20708057/how-do-you-make-a-less-mixin-for-gradients-with-a-variable-number-of-stops) allows for change of origin, and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049951/less-linear-gradient-mixin) also has useful info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a mixin with parameter, add your parameters starting with @, comma separated between the () after the mixinname. `mixin(@paramter1:defaultvalue, @paramter2:defaultvalue)`.

So in your case:

```
.gradient (@degrees:0)
{
  /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(@degrees,  rgba(245,246,246,0) 0%, rgba(236,237,239,0) 10%, rgba(219,220,226,0.22) 30%, rgba(184,186,198,0.5) 55%, rgba(221,223,227,0.78) 80%, rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(245,246,246,0)), color-stop(10%,rgba(236,237,239,0)), color-stop(30%,rgba(219,220,226,0.22)), color-stop(55%,rgba(184,186,198,0.5)), color-stop(80%,rgba(221,223,227,0.78)), color-stop(100%,rgba(245,246,246,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(@degrees,  rgba(245,246,246,0) 0%,rgba(236,237,239,0) 10%,rgba(219,220,226,0.22) 30%,rgba(184,186,198,0.5) 55%,rgba(221,223,227,0.78) 80%,rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(@degrees,  rgba(245,246,246,0) 0%,rgba(236,237,239,0) 10%,rgba(219,220,226,0.22) 30%,rgba(184,186,198,0.5) 55%,rgba(221,223,227,0.78) 80%,rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(@degrees,  rgba(245,246,246,0) 0%,rgba(236,237,239,0) 10%,rgba(219,220,226,0.22) 30%,rgba(184,186,198,0.5) 55%,rgba(221,223,227,0.78) 80%,rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient((@degrees - 90deg),  rgba(245,246,246,0) 0%,rgba(236,237,239,0) 10%,rgba(219,220,226,0.22) 30%,rgba(184,186,198,0.5) 55%,rgba(221,223,227,0.78) 80%,rgba(245,246,246,1) 100%); /* W3C */
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#00f5f6f6', endColorstr='#f5f6f6',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
```

The [second link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049951/less-linear-gradient-mixin) of @ seems useful to correct the degrees i use here `background: linear-gradient((@degrees - 90deg)`.

The old `-webkit-gradient()` doesn't support degrees (AFAIK, see: https://www.webkit.org/blog/175/introducing-css-gradients/) and the `filter` doesn't too.